# How can I add buttons dynamically to a WPF application?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am new to WPF and i want to create a window which will create a variable number of buttons with an image.

```
List<Button> HeroButtons = new List<Button>();


for (int i=0;i<20;i++)

    HeroButtons.Add(new Button(){});

foreach( Button but in HeroButtons)
{
    var brush = new ImageBrush();
    brush.ImageSource = new BitmapImage(new Uri("Resources/lina.png", UriKind.Relative));
    but.Background = brush;                
}
```

Nothing appears if I run the application.

Comment: You haven't added the buttons to your window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give your grid or other container a name, then use that name (ie Grid1) to add children.

```cs
foreach (Button but in HeroButtons)
{
    Grid1.Children.Add(but);
}
```

Comment: Worked like  a charm! Is there any possibility to put them one after the other ? I've tried `button.Left` but it is not available.

Comment: Really I got down voted, for what?
Anyways, I'd suggest using a for loop instead of a for each. It's slightly more efficient and it will allow you to control the order of how things are inserted. (which will be partially be determined by the order added into HeroButtons)
If you want them to be in different locations assign them to a variable button before adding it to HeroButtons.
I'd also suggest combining the for-loops into one.